# How did Picard's away team transport so far in First Contact and not be detected by the Vulcans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-first-contact

The Enterprise E [transporter has a range of 40,000 km](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transporter), yet Picard's team beamed up at least 360,000 km from Earth to Enterprise hiding near the moon, and the Vulcan sensors never detected the transport (AFAIK).

> PICARD: Picard to Enterprise. Energise.
>
> [Enterprise-E bridge]
>
> PICARD: Report.
>
> WORF: The moon's gravitational field obscured our warp signature. The Vulcans did not detect us.

In Bozeman, Montana, on April 5, 2063 [the moon will be closest around 7:00pm](https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/usa/bozeman?month=4&year=2063) which is about the right time we saw the T'plana-Hath land. But, earlier, LaForge showed Cochrane the Enterprise in orbit through a telescope, so she was plainly visible if the Vulcan ship arrived - and the Vulcans will have sensors. When Picard beamed up, the Enterprise was hiding in the Moon's gravitational field, and I have to assume she was also hiding from Vulcan visual sensors. This means she had to be no less than 363,104 km away in the best case scenario.

So there are two distinct problems here: The distance transported, and transporting without Vulcan detection by the survey ship's sensors.

How did Picard transport to the Enterprise, which was hiding its warp signature in the Moon's gravitational field and hiding from sight? Why wasn't the transport picked up on Vulcan sensors?

- I'm assuming the Vulcan ship is smart enough to see everything orbiting Earth to avoid hitting anything, like the [thousands of satellites](https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/article/solar-systems-biggest-junkyard) drifting around up there. A starship within 40,000 km might be easy to spot?

Comment: Presumably the Enterprise has a total understanding of the technical capacity (and shortcomings) of the Vulcan's ships and sensory array

Comment: That's 1/2 of the problem.

Comment: They pull the same schtick when they make the cloak on Lursa's ship activate.

Comment: Hmm. Could the Enterprise be directly between the moon and the Earth?

Comment: Could be but that puts them in a direct visual line of sight that even Cochrane's little telescope can see. Actually a third problem is that a geostationary orbit is 43,000 km above the equator. You can't physically "park" above Bozeman Montana (that's just too much for one question).

Comment: Shouldn't the question be, why doesn't every scriptwriter have at least a Bachelor's degree in physics?

Comment: Well then what would I ever do with my SE time?

Comment: You can't *park* there, but you can linger anywhere under sufficient thrust.

Comment: do we have evidence that 21st century Vulcan ships can detect 24th century Federation transporters, thus making a canon conflict occur here?

Comment: @Cadence - I know what was possible if they weren't trying to be discreet. This situation was unique - sitting within transporter range, avoiding first contact with earth, while also hiding from the warp-capable Vulcans. It's a good trick.

Comment: Most likely something similar to how the Defiant was able to get away with transporting people about right under the TOS Enterprise's nose in Trial and Tribbleations which was something about doing it in between scanning pulses.

Comment: Interesting   . .

Comment: The first official "Star Trek" novel, "Spock Must Die" by James Blish, involved Scotty developing a new kind of transporter that had a much greater range. Maybe some of the technology, refined, made it into transporters by Picard's time? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock_Must_Die!

Comment: To answer this question, we must assume that "masked by the moon..." does not imply proximity.  The easiest way to hide from another ship is to block line of sight.  So they could just be in geosynchronous orbit on the other side of the planet.  I don't think line of sight is necessarily required for transporters to function; transporters are always available when a ship is in orbit.

Comment: @BAMF4bacon true but their specifications also say the range is not unlimited. In the question, I found 40,000 km to be the accepted range. Enterprise would have to be below geosynchronous orbit and directly above Bozeman for the transporter (that we know) to work.

Comment: I read the memory alpha page... it says in at least one spot that the Enterprise D has a range of 40k.  Seeing all the improved transporter technology available in Star Trek, I don't think it's a stretch to believe that they increased that 10x for the Enterprise E. Certainly convenient ... but not a shocking development.

Comment: @VogonPoet  And clearly, transporters work from all over orbit, so that 40k number is a bit spurious.  Nobody says "hold on 20 minutes; we are on the other side of the planet..."

Comment: Yes but MA does say 24th century transporters are 40,000k, and E is 24th century. Anything else is pure speculation.

Comment: Not to mention that in TOS they could transport to earth, requiring minimum of 36,000 km for geosynchronous orbit, would have worked in TOS, 200 years before now.  It's not the first time Star Trek has got the numbers mixed up.  It was clearly established in TOS warp 6 travelled 20 light years in one day.  But suddenly in the Voyager universe, it's like 100x slower.  MEEP.

Comment: It’s almost like those script writers don’t even *read* memory alpha. Geez!

Comment: It is absolutely true that writer's goal is to tell a story.  The "technobabble" -- as they call it -- is a secondary or last consideration.  Many times the only reasonable answer to an inconsistency/question is "because writers wrote it that way."  Also many times directors or editors will make changes because they like the way the dialogue sounds or flows better, perhaps to help with a scene transition. The last thing they are considering is canonized facts.  There is a lot of reading you can do to see how this evolved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_technical_manuals

Comment: @BAMF4bacon  Didn't you ever have to do time, speed, and distance problems in school?  Starship crews would have to do that constantly to figure out how long a trip will take, or what warp factor to use to get to the destination in time.  Distance divided by speed to get travel time is not technobabble,  it is simple mathematics.  And the same thing goes for the range of transporters once it is established.  Though as early as "Gamesters of Triskellion" and "Assignment Earth" it was shown that aadvanced alien transporters had interstellar range &thus that range improvement was possible.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's safe to assume that ship sensors in Star Trek aren't omnipresent and active all the time. There are tons of instances where teleportations aren't detected, when it's convenient for the plot, throughout several episodes of different shows. Intruders boarding by beaming are typically revealed by crewmen or sensors inside the ship.

In a similar way, it seems to happen rather often that ships hide successfully behind or inside celestial bodies. The Vulcans most likely fell for their logic here: If there's been any active warp effect, it's more than likely only the strongest remaining trail will lead to the ship in question. Once they found it, there's no need to scan for more, since from their point of view there shouldn't have been any around there to begin with. They were looking for one anomaly and there's one they've found.

In addition to these points, I think the far bigger plothole are the Borg: While the Vulcans clearly visited Earth before (as shown in Enterprise for example), their scans for warp capable vessels should have revealed at least some debris of technology too advanced for Earth. Whenever a crew is looking for another ship, they'll always notice and track potential debris. Maybe the Vulcans just gave up too early, being fascinated by a warp capable phallus crossing their viewport. ;)

Comment: OK but what about the 360,000 km transport to the moon? If they’re hiding behind a celestial body... “beam me to the moon, Scotty?”

Comment: @VogonPoet Basically. ;) It's a stretch and according to [this question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11101/in-star-trek-canon-whats-the-range-of-operation-of-transporters) TOS era transports are up to around 40,000km according to the writer's guide, but that might have changed in later versions. Also we don't exactly know the Vulcan vessel's approach to earth. It's certainly possible that the Enterprise was still between Earth and Moon at this point, while hidden behind Earth.

Answer (score 4):

**TRANSPORTER**
It is important to understand that from a writer's perspective, the transporter was a necessary invention to keep the TV shows plot moving: characters don't spend time travelling, just bouncing from adventure to adventure.  It's purpose was not to subplant intersteller travel, that is this ships' job.  From this perspective, 10,000 to 400,000 are small number compare to 1 light year (9.4 billion killometers.

Trolling related posts, I found this gem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_%28Star_Trek%29#Capabilities_and_limitations

Which establishes TOS era transporters had a range of 40,000 km according to the tech manual.  This makes sense, as earth's geosynchronous orbit is 35,786 km.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_orbit  The original article also points out the transporter is a particularly troublesome piece of technical writing, with several inconsistencies.  Moreover, our understanding of quantum mechanics has improved from almost nothing in 1967, making much of the "science fiction" of the transporter now "debunked."

There is no reference to how Transporter range has improved over time, except for the numerous examples of improved transporter technology we see employed multiple times in various episodes.

Then there is this:
https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/transporter-range.275253/

So it would seem not even die hard star trek researching nerds can agree.  And that's likely because writers have been too nebulous on the subject to be certain.  This makes sense to a certain degree: why quibble over the transporter's distance.  You can't do interstellar travel with it.  That's the key point.

In light of all this, I'm fit to submit this data point to say, "look!  they beamed from Montana to the moon.  So Enterprise E has at least 300k km transporter range.

**BEING UNDETECTED**
The Enterprise has superior intelligence.  They know exactly what sort of craft will appear, when and where.  Using this information, it is simple to evade detection.  This alone explains their ability to be undetected.

But they also have superior technology and superior knowledge of the limitations of the Vulcan's technology.  Given time, a solution can easily be found.  They probably would just have to look up "known sensor blindness of Vulcan sensor array " in their computer.

Comment: I agree with all points, I think the information belongs on this site because, while writers may get sloppy and nebulous, they create problems when they want to create a crisis in a future release. If they ever revisit 24th century earth, they can no longer say "Captain! We are out of transporter range!" near *any* planet, because the audience just literally watched them beam a team to the moon, from what the dialogue seems to say. And if the Enterprise was on the other side of Earth, well, beaming through rock is obviously not a valid plot device either.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment.  I think the issue is not having the information available, but rather having the production team consistently use it.  Their focus is to produce a good story on a schedule, and this is not near the top of their priority list.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it is not explained, whether in the movie, the script or the novelization. They just did.

We can try to find a plausible explanation in-universe, but it would be pure conjecture.